# Http request - already connected

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

Basically I've been using these particular lines of code for quite some time and never had problems with it. Nothing's been touched but now I'm getting

> IllegalStateException - Already connected

exactly after I set `conn.setUsesCaches(false)`

```
 public void PutImageToS3(String signedUrl, Bitmap image) throws WampNetworkException, IOException {
            URL url = new URL(signedUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.getDoOutput();
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
            conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
            conn.addRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
            OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                throw new IOException("Failed to upload image to S3: "
                        + conn.getResponseCode() + conn.getResponseMessage() + "\r\n");
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            conn.disconnect();
        }
```

Comment: You should always share print stack trace while posting question.

Answer (score 0):

Write this code in `try-finally` block and then try

```
public void PutImageToS3(String signedUrl, Bitmap image) throws WampNetworkException, IOException {

       try{
        URL url = new URL(signedUrl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.getDoOutput();
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
        conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
        conn.addRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
        OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            throw new IOException("Failed to upload image to S3: "
                    + conn.getResponseCode() + conn.getResponseMessage() + "\r\n");
        }
     }
     finally{
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        conn.disconnect();
      }
    }
```

Comment: try after removing the if that throws Exception

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the request *before* getting the response code.

Move the `close()` before `getResponseCode()`, and remove the redundant `flush()`.

NB Why are you calling `getDoOutput()` and ignoring the result?

Comment: I don't have a result, it's a put function, just uploading a pic. But I also don't set that anywhere, might as well remove it :) But question is why did it stop working?

Comment: It stopped working because you tried to get the response code before you had completely written the request. You don't have a result *because* you're not storing it anywhere. The call to `getDoOutput()` is pointless. Remove it.

Comment: It is removed now, it was pointless but harmless in this case. Where does the "tried to get the response code before you had completely written the request" happen?

Answer (score 0):

Amazing solution has been found! There was a problem with the router today so uploading is hell. Once switched to internet from provider it worked like a charm :) GG!